# Length is showing 0 even after using async and await keyword

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, async-await, firebase-storage

I Dont know what is going on but even after using async and await keyword still the length is showing zero. Thanks in advance.

```
const commercial_shoots = [];
  let test;
  React.useEffect(() => {
    async function fetchData() {
      const app_ref = ref(storage, "Home/");
      await listAll(app_ref)
        .then((res) => {
          res.items.forEach((itemRef) => {
            getDownloadURL(itemRef).then((url) => {
              commercial_shoots.push({ img: url });
            });
          });
        })
        .catch((error) => {
          console.log(error);
        });
    }
    fetchData();
  }, []);
  return <div>{commercial_shoots.length}</div>;
};
```

Comment: Could you post the entire component please?

Answer (score 1):

React only re-renders the component when `state` or `props` updates. Here, you are only updating a local variable. So, even when it updates, the UI does not reflect the change.

The solution would be to use `commercialShoots` as a state in the component.

```js
const CommercialShoots = () => {
  const [commercialShoots, setCommercialShoots] = useState([]);
  useEffect(() => {
    async function fetchData() {
     try {
      const app_ref = ref(storage, "Home/");
      const res = await listAll(app_ref);
      const downloadUrls = await Promise.all(res.items.map(itemRef) => getDownloadURL(itemRef));
      const mappedUrlsToImg = downloadUrls.map((url) => ({ img: url });
      setCommercialShoots(mappedUrlsToImg);
     } catch (error) {
      console.error(error);
     }
    }
    fetchData();
  }, []);
  return <div>{commercial_shoots.length}</div>;
};
```

**NOTE** - Since we are using `async / await` extensively, I took the liberty of updating the `.then()` to `async / await` syntax.